# Ruby on Rails OOP - I know about nested/inner classes, what about nested 'records'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, software-design

I've a record/model that's filled up with a lot of boolean flags, short strings, misc settings, etc, and I want to refactor them into an encapsulated class.

I would normally create an inner class for the parent to 'own', but what's the best practice in Rails?

- Just leaving everything in the record?  [composed_of](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods/composed_of)? Not very clean though.
- Serializing? Becomes not easily searchable + overhead + extensibility issues. Still not clean.
- Create another record, associate it, and [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/Module/delegate)? But have to delegate and manage assignment, aliases (boolean? fields), create/save callbacks, more stuff I'm unaware of...
- Is there a way to create in 'inner record'?
- Another way?

An example would be having a table `Client`, with a low number of rows 10~20. Each `Client` is has long list of options, currently stored under `Client` columns. So there are fields such as:

```
c = Client.find(1)
c.theme_color # "blue"
c.session_timeout_seconds # 1800
c.branding_logo # "client_a.png"
c.require_logout_confirmation # true
```

In a pure OOP system without rails, I would refactor these "instance variables" into a nested `Client::Options` class. Then all the options become organized inside a single nested class and are encapsulated inside `Client`. This way, nobody else needs to know that `Client::Options` and `Client` are closely related (they would still just message `c.theme_color` without knowing that `Client` will delegate the call to `Client::Options` within), and this would also become a loosely-coupled refactoring since no other classes or method calls need to change.

However, the nested class thing isn't possible (as far as I know) in rails, so I'm looking for a 'best practices' solution.

Comment: seems like it will generate overly opinionated answers. I don't know though.

Comment: Well then that means there isn't a 'best practice', and I'll just have to make do with some custom solution.

Comment: Why do you want to refactor into an encapsulated class? Because it makes sense (they belong together, it should be another entity), to share it, to more easily extend it? Maybe a more specific example to demonstrate might help.

Comment: Added an example. Yeah, they do belong together. That's why I would've had the options inside a nested class. So far, it seems like the prevailing answer is 'no, there aren't nested records' and to just have all these fields populate the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up going with:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :option_set, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true, :validate => true, :inverse_of => :client
  before_create :build_option_set

  # accesses all these fields through OptionSet
  # :allow_nil is required or else delegation will fail - it appears delegation occurs before :build_option_set
  delegate_option_set_args = [
    :option_a,
    :option_b,
    :option_c,
    # etc
  ].map { |f| [f, :"#{f}=", :"#{f}?" ] }.flatten << { :to => :option_set, :allow_nil => true }

  delegate(*delegate_option_set_args)
end


class OptionSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :client_id
  validates_inclusion_of :option_c, :in => [ "foo", "bar", "buzz", "fizz" ]
  belongs_to :client, :inverse_of => :option_set
end
```

Now, although `OptionSet` is still accessible from "outside" of `Client`, it still effectively encapsulates all these fields into their own class. Accessing these fields should be done via messaging the `Client`, e.g. `Client.first.option_a`, rather than modifying the `OptionSet`. Additional work can be done to enforce that `OptionSet` is not modified directly.

I've not found a way to instantiate the option fields at the same time as `Client` creation, though:

```
client = Client.create!(client_args)
client.update_arguments!(
  :option_a => 1,
  :option_b => false,
  :option_c => "foo"
)
```